# IOS macros issues

Tags: ios, objective-c, macros, ios7

I have a small issues with macros
I have the following macro declared on project-Prefix.pch file

```
#define IS_IOS7_AND_UP ([[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue] >= 7.0)
```

and I have a macrofile.h which contain the following code, but when I compile I got error "Invalid token at start of a preprocessor expression"

```
#if (IS_IOS7_AND_UP>0)  //error-> "Invalid token at start of a preprocessor expression"
#define CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH 320.0f
#else
#define CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH 300.0f
#endif
```

Can you please tell me what's wrong about this, actually I need this to be a macro which prevent me of changing many files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to do exactly what you are saying. Instead, try defining `CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH` like this:

```
#define CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH (IS_IOS7_AND_UP ? 320.0 : 300.0)
```

This will do the check at runtime without changing any of your existing code.